# What does ピクンッ mean?

Tags: definitions, onomatopoeia

I came across an image on Deviantart that has Japanese text written on it, so I am trying to translate it. You can see it here: https://www.deviantart.com/ryonapage/art/Dominated-710481249 (Warning: Not Safe For Work)

The part that I'm stuck on is the onomatopoeia ピクンッ. I found out from the website (http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/search/?keyword=%E3%83%94%E3%82%AF&submitSearch=Search+SFX&x=) that ピクッ means *twitch*. But it doesn't have ピクンッ listed. Is it some sort of  variant?

If you know the answer, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ピクンッ is a variation of ピク. It describes a fast jerky muscle movement. `ン`, `ッ` and `ンッ` can be somewhat arbitrarily added to make an onomatopoeia "stronger".

- バタ = バタッ = バタン = バタンッ
- ドキ = ドキッ = ドキン = ドキンッ
- ペタ = ペタッ = ペタン = ペタンッ
- キラ = キラッ = キラン = キランッ

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stumped by this, but I think you cleared it up for me! (Grin)